# postgresql apply distinct among one of the column in SELECT

Tags: postgresql, distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, from Table_E
```

If I want to only consider COL_A's duplication, how to use DISTINCT properly only for the COL_A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (COL_A) COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D FROM Table_E;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)